# Parse group by equivalent query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a message board app, where you can imagine multiple users posting multiple topics to start a discussion. What I want is to have a sorted of overview for the message boards where I only show the latest post from each user. So if `User A` and `User B` are posting in a board for themselves, I want to just show the last item posted by either `User A` or `User B`. I tried a few things on my own with the `whereMatchesKeyInQuery` query constraint which comes really close to my desired effect, but I still get multiple items from a single user when I use that method. Effectively I want to group each board by user posts.

Current query

```
    ParseQuery<ContactObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ContactObject.class);
    ParseQuery<MessageObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery(MessageObject.class);
    query2.whereMatchesKeyInQuery(MConstants.CODE, MConstants.MSG_FROM, query);
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried already, and explain how it does not work.

Comment: The issue as I explained before is that I get all results from the table with the query, where as I really only want the latest post made by each user. The query I currently use will be added to the question @Handsomeguy